# Possible to determine whether a Windows server has time synchronization enabled?

Tags: windows-server-2003, time-synchronization

A customer asked me to take a look at his Windows 2003 server and tell him whether the server has an active time synchronization with a time server.

I thought I can use the command:

```
w32tm /query /status
```

But it seems that the `/query` option is not available in Windows 2003 server.

**My question is:**

How can I figure out the current time server settings (command line or GUI)?

Comment: Bad, but easy, idea -- adjust the time my ~30 seconds.  See if it corrects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
net time /querysntp
```